# Count items with value in angularjs scope per row

Tags: angularjs, scope, count

I have a site that uses angular ng-repeat to show data from my scope and all works fine, but I need to count items to show a percentage complete, but can't seem to find a solution online. I am still very new to Angular and JS, so apologies if its an easy solution.

The below is a simplified and generalized example of what I am looking to achieve:

```
$scope.devices = [
{Detail_A:'ShowA1',Detail_B:'ShowB1',Status_A:'',Status_B:'OK',Status_C:'',Status_D:'OK',ENG_A:'OK',ENG_B:'OK',ENG_C:'OK'},
{Detail_A:'ShowA2',Detail_B:'ShowB2',Status_A:'OK',Status_B:'OK',Status_C:'OK',Status_D:'OK',ENG_A:'',ENG_B:'',ENG_C:''},
{Detail_A:'ShowA3',Detail_B:'ShowB3',Status_A:'OK',Status_B:'OK',Status_C:'OK',Status_D:'OK',ENG_A:'OK',ENG_B:'OK',ENG_C:'OK'}
]
```

I would like to show a percentage of items that state 'OK' within the two pre-fixed items: Status_* and ENG_*. This can be either by having to loop each one or better to be able to use the prefix to calculate over a group.

```
<div ng-repeat="device in devices">
<div class="col-md-2">{{StatusPercentComplete}}</div>
<div class="col-md-1">{{ENGPercentComplete}}</div>
<div class="col-md-1">{{device.Detail_A}}</div>
<div class="col-md-1">{{device.Detail_B}}</div>
</div>
```

So for row 1, StatusPercentComplete would be 50% and ENGPercentComplete would be 100%.

Any direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put together a little proof of concept with a refactored percent calculation function, so that you can reuse it for either `Status_x` or `ENG_x` keys. You can also use a percentage filter on the bound html element if you don't want to construct the `number%` string in the controller function.

Note: this solution uses lodash for the filtering (which tends to be a standard dependency in angular applications, but just so you know...)

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function() {
    var ctrl = this;
    
    ctrl.devices = [
      {Detail_A:'ShowA1',Detail_B:'ShowB1',Status_A:'',Status_B:'OK',Status_C:'',Status_D:'OK',ENG_A:'OK',ENG_B:'OK',ENG_C:'OK'},
      {Detail_A:'ShowA2',Detail_B:'ShowB2',Status_A:'OK',Status_B:'OK',Status_C:'OK',Status_D:'OK',ENG_A:'',ENG_B:'',ENG_C:''},
      {Detail_A:'ShowA3',Detail_B:'ShowB3',Status_A:'OK',Status_B:'OK',Status_C:'OK',Status_D:'OK',ENG_A:'OK',ENG_B:'OK',ENG_C:'OK'}
    ];
    
    ctrl.percentComplete = function(keyString, item) {
      var statuses = _.filter(_.keys(item), function(key) {
        return key.substring(0, keyString.length) === keyString;
      });
      var okStatuses = _.filter(statuses, function(status) {
        return item[status] === 'OK';
      });
        
      return okStatuses.length / statuses.length * 100 + '%';
    };

  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="lodash.js@4.6.1" data-semver="4.6.1" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.6.1/lodash.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <div ng-repeat="device in main.devices" class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">{{main.percentComplete('Status', device)}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2">{{main.percentComplete('ENG', device)}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2">{{device.Detail_A}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2">{{device.Detail_B}}</div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked great thanks in my dev environment, so will try in prod now. It's great how dynamic it is and easy alter to my needs. lodash is new to me so will look further into it as looks to be a great tool.

Comment: @bennet-adams This has been working great, but what is the reason for declaring var ctrl = this and then calling the controller as Main? It works great, but I have trouble doing other changes to scope due to the var, mostly likely from my lack of understanding.

Comment: It's a good practice to use ["controller as" syntax](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) to keep scoped variables explicitly tied to a particular controller, especially for nested scopes. It's not strictly necessary, and you'll still need to inject $scope for watchers and event listeners, but it's the recommended way for angular ^1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant something like this?

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,val) in devices" ng-init="calculateValues(key, val)">
  <div class="col-md-2">{{foo[key].StatusPercentComplete / foo[key].StatusSize  * 100}} %</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">{{foo[key].ENGPercentComplete / foo[key].ENGSize * 100}} %</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">{{val.Detail_A}}</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">{{val.Detail_B}}</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.foo = [];

$scope.calculateValues = function(key, value){
  $scope.foo[key] = {
    StatusPercentComplete: 0,
    StatusSize: 0,
    ENGPercentComplete: 0,
    ENGSize: 0
  };
  for(var property in value){
    if(property.indexOf("ENG_") == 0){
      $scope.foo[key].ENGPercentComplete += (value[property] == "OK" ? 1 : 0);
      $scope.foo[key].ENGSize++;
    }
    if(property.indexOf("Status_") == 0){
      $scope.foo[key].StatusPercentComplete += (value[property] == "OK" ? 1 : 0);
      $scope.foo[key].StatusSize++;
    }
  }
}
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/LjvwhdMvKl9Ntk3q9pbA?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I got it to work but didn't seem to update my percentages on the fly as I updated the form values as the previous solution had. I didn't think of a dictionary approach so will certainly add it to my book of tools :)